# Convergence of: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin(nx)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

Need help with checking: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin(nx)}{n}$

for point-wise convergence and uniform convergence of: ${-\pi} \leq x \leq {\pi}$.

Comment: well it is the Fourier series of $\dfrac x2$ in this interval...

Comment: yes that is true, but as i understand it the series doesn't converge to $\frac{x}{2}$ at every point in the interval

Comment: in $(-\pi,\pi)$ it will be $\frac x2$ (repeated every $2\pi$). At multiples of $\pi$ it will be $0$ ($0=\frac {\pi/2-\pi/2}2$). Did you get something else?

Comment: (to detail a little) the values at $-\pi$ and $\pi$ will be $0$ because of the jump from $-\frac {\pi}2$ to $+\frac {\pi}2$. At a jump discontinuity of first order the value is at the middle ($\frac {-\pi/2+\pi/2}2$). (my first comment should have been $\frac x2$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$ and not $[-\pi,\pi]$...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Abel's uniform convergence test. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test). Or you can use the following theorem:

Theorem: The Fourier series of a 2π-periodic continuous and piecewise smooth function converges uniformly.

Comment: To apply Abel's test we need that $g_n(x)=\sin(nx)$ is a monotone sequence of functions, i.e. $\sin(nx)\leq \sin((n+1)x)$ for all $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ and all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which is not the case. Hence, we can't apply Abel's test.