# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n\mathop=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin2\pi nx}{\pi n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove $$x-\lfloor x\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}=-\sum_{n\mathop =1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{\pi n}$$
>   where $x$ is any non-integer real number.

Comment: Every term of the series has $1$ as a period. Therefore the sum of the series (if it exists, which it does) must have $1$ as a period. For proving convergence, distinguish between $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$, and for the latter, use the Dirichlet test.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: Two related computations (though somewhat more complicated) are at these two links: [MSE link I](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439266/fourier-series-for-x-x-frac12) and [MSE link II](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280282/evaluating-sum-k-1-infty-frac-sin-leftk-theta-rightk2u1-with-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin t=\Im(e^{it})\quad=>\qquad\frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{2\pi n}=\Im\bigg(\frac{e^{2\pi inx}}{2\pi n}\bigg)=\Im\int e^{2\pi inx}dx\qquad=>$$

$$\sum_1^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{2\pi n}=\Im\int\sum_1^\infty e^{2\pi inx}dx=\Im\int\frac{e^{2\pi ix}}{1-e^{2\pi ix}}dx=-\Im\bigg[\frac{\ln(1-e^{2\pi ix})}{2\pi}\bigg]$$

Of course, the whole catch is to pay attention to the branches of the [complex logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

Comment: This is wrong. $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty e^{2\pi inx}dx$ is divergent...

Comment: There are methods of [ascribing finite values to divergent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series), by way of [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation). See [generality of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generality_of_algebra) for a similar example.